# How can i use map correctly in Haskell

Tags: haskell, higher-order-functions, option-type

I am trying to make a program, that takes a letter and turns that letter into **Morse code**.
The Morse table is given, as well as `charToCode :: [(Char, String)] -> Char -> String`

I also have to use *lookup* and *fromJust* form Data.Maybe to make this work. Upon compiling i receive the following error:

```
Couldn't match expected type [Maybe Char]
            with actual type Maybe String
    * In the second argument of 'map', namely '(lookup a f)'
      In the expression: map (fromJust) (lookup a f)
      In an equation for 'charToCode':
          charToCode f a = map (fromJust) (lookup a f)
```

I **have** to use the map from Prelude. Here is my code so far:

```
morseTab :: [(Char, String)]
morseTab = [('A', ".-"), ('B', "-..."), ('C', "-.-."), ('D', "-.."), ('E', "."), ('F', "..-."), ('G', "--."), ('H', "...."),('I', ".."), ('J', ".---"), ('K', "-.-"), ('L', ".-.."), ('M', "--"), ('N', "-."), ('O', "---"), ('P', ".--."), ('Q', "--.-"), ('R', ".-."), ('S', "..."), ('T', "-"), ('U', "..-"), ('V', "...-"), ('W', ".--"), ('X', "-..-"), ('Y', "-.--"), ('Z', "--..")]
charToCode :: [(Char, String)] -> Char -> String
charToCode f a = map (fromJust) (lookup a f)
```

morseTab is a given function, i can't make changes to it either.

Comment: You should not use `map`. The result of `lookup a f` is a `Maybe String`, not a list of `Maybe String`s.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem is there a way to make my Maybe String into a list that contains only that one Maybe String element? And than pass that to map

Answer (score 1):

You should not use `map`. The result of `lookup a f` is a `Maybe String`, not a list of `Maybe String`s.

You thus can use `fromJust` with:

```
import Data.Maybe(fromJust)

charToCode :: [(Char, String)] -> Char -> String
charToCode f a = fromJust (lookup a f)
```

That being said, using `fromJust` is unsafe: it does not take into account that `lookup a f` might return a `Nothing`.

Comment: I did this the first time, but my mentor declined it unfortunately, because i have to use a higher function somehow. She suggested the map function

Comment: @BarnaMikler: i think this is more because you use `lookup`, and because `fromJust` is by some not considered good code design: it will error in case `lookup` does not find anything.

Comment: Here is the description of the excercise(roughly translated): "Write a function that takes a character and with the help of morseTab it turns it into morse code. You can assume, that the character is in the morseTab table. Use a higher function (map). (Help: on the internet, see what lookup and fromJust do)     charToCode :: [(Char, String)] -> Char -> String". By this i feel like i have to use map,lookup and fromJust :/

Comment: @BarnaMikler: you will need to use map to translate an entire string into morse...